# How to get list of SSL/TLS ciphers supported by internet explorer

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, ssl, encryption, browser

We are going to develop an SSL server which support all the ciphers supported by IE 10 and IE 11. So I started searching in google about the list of ciphers supported by IE, but I am not able to get a single user document which clearly mentions all SSL ciphers supported by IE.

Is there any user document available in internet or is there any way to directly check the IE browser settings to get the list of supported ciphers ?

Comment: Why? Just do nothing, so you support all the cipher suites that are supported by your SSL implementation. The SSL handshake with the browser will do the rest. You don't need this information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qualys SSL Labs publishes a more graphical view. Select your desired version of IE and OS from the list for more details.

- https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html

Answer (score 9):

The cipher suites depend less on the version of Internet Explorer and more on the underlying OS, because IE uses the SChannel implementation from Windows. And with some help of google it is easy to get the following information:

- cipher suites in Schannel: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374757(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- cipher suites in Schannel on Vista: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468651(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- ciphers in IE7..10 on various Windows versions: https://github.com/client9/sslassert/wiki/IE-Supported-Cipher-Suites

Apart from that, why would you want to implement all cipher suites supported by IE? Some of them are only to connect to legacy SSL implementations. The usual way is to support a number of secure ciphers, enough so that one finds a shared cipher with the common client implementations.